# How to fix 'Bundler could not install a gem because it needs to create a directory, but a file exists'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, gemfile

`bundle update` is failing with the following message `Bundler could not install a gem because it needs to create a directory, but a file exists`

This occurs after editing a line in the Gemfile so that a gem is fetched from Github.

I have never seen this error before, and am struggling to understand how to resolve it or to find any useful information online.

I've ensured that bundler, rubygems and other relevant parts of my system are up-to-date.

The bundler source indicates that this error is raised if coping to the destination fails. Line 117 https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb

So I have tried removing the offending gem from the Gemfile, running bundle update and cleaning the gemset to remove all previous traces before re-adding and re-installing the gem.

The error is still raised when fetching from github, but disappears when using rubygems.

How to resolve this?

Comment: to start with, run `bundle install --verbose` to get a hint

Comment: thanks @RubyRacer. `--verbose` does not provide anything more than the message mentioned above. The bundle action fails very quickly, before even a connection is established. So I assume this is a local problem rather than something that is failing during the download / unpack / copy actions. Scratching my head. Grateful for any more ideas.

Comment: I see that the error provided information about the file. Doesn't this help?

Comment: it indicates where the problem may be, but not how to resolve it. I have removed the gem from the gem file, and then run bundle update and gem cleanup. I have also run gem uninstall. I would expect this to remove all offending files/folders, yet the problem persists. Are there other steps I should be taking to remove any conflicting files/ folders?